# In 'IDA PRO', let 'IDAPython' import default module at startup

Tags: python, ida

We know 'IDAPython' loads several modules by default at startup, such as idaapi, idautils.... I wrote a module to let python print all numbers as hex format in the command window, which I wish can be imported each time when python loads  those default modules. how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file `%APPDATA%\Hex-Rays\IDA Pro\idapythonrc.py` with the following content:

```
import idaapi
idaapi.require('mymodule')
```

With this file in place, you can even keep `mymodule.py` in the same directory.

P.S. IDA can tell you the path to this directory, too, which could be handy on other OSes or if the relevant company name changes again ;-).  Just enter:

```
get_user_idadir()
```

at the prompt.